# How to Display text file (.txt) in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

How to Display text file (.txt) in jetpack compose.

**Explanation:**

Need to show (.txt) file on the screen using Jetpack compose

Comment: Please add a bit more information. Where does this text file come from, What/How do you want to display this? etc

Comment: So, you're getting .txt file from remote or your local storage?

Comment: Local file path

Comment: i guess there is no way.
soyou have to convert that txt file into string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Just read text into some value

```
val text = File("example.txt").readText()
```

Thus, all text from your file will be in that string value.

### And create `@Composable` text function with this value

```
@Composable    
Text(text = text)
```